# Is it possible to purchase Visual Studio 2010 Premium Edition with out the MSDN subscription?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

As the title states...

"Is it possible to purchase Visual Studio 2010 Premium Edition with out the MSDN subscription?"

We would like to purchase VS 2010 Premium but do not need the MSDN subscription. is this possible? if so where?

Comment: Purchase an MSDN Subscription instead.  Visual Studio is included.  And lots more.  Not attractive if you nickel and dime your tools.

Comment: Unfortunately my employer does nickel and dime their tools! Or at least when they buy them.  I can't even get them to invest a mere $1000 to purchase an issue management system to support their software maintenance and development. I had to haggle them to consider getting Premium edition. I guess it's gonna have to be Pro edition.

Comment: Depending on what kind of organization you work for, maybe you could look at the BizSpark programme or the Microsoft Partner thing or some other similar programmme where MS gives you access to the dev tools cheaply.

Comment: Yeah I brought up the BizSpark option but our company does not qualify.

Comment: Hmya, you can't afford an employer like that.  The days of plodding along with outdated or missing tools are gone, listing the ones you know and master are important bullet items on your resume.  If your employer can guarantee you employment until retirement then plod on.  If not, you are much better off finding another one.

Comment: Hans, Your preaching to the choir. This company has scraped by on a legacy line of business application for 15 years now, the two old timers that wrote and maintain it are out of touch with software tools and techniques that have come about in the last 8 years. Now that I got them interested in the .Net platform I also have to sell them on doing things in a more tried and true manner rather than the old way, this has not been easy and I am on the verge of throwing in the towel.

Comment: @JBeckton, I feel for you. Did you get what you need in the haggling, or you found another employer? (This is a 5 years super old thread, I know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft's own [page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison), this is not an option. And I doubt it would save you much money anyway if it was an option. The difference for the Pro version is just $400, and since the Premium is $5469 in theory you'd get down to $5069.

Comment: We can get the Pro edition without the MSDN for around $700. We just purchased a couple 2008 server licenses and sql server 2008 5 months ago. So we do not really need the MSDN.

Comment: @JBeckton: Yes, but the price difference for MSDN seems to be about $400, and the price difference between Pro and Premium seems to be about $4,300. So if your managers don't want to pay the extra $400, I'd assume that they'd be very unwilling to pay the extra $4,300 for Premium anyway?

Comment: I'm just going to give them their only two options VS pro without or Premium with MSDN. They can take it from there.

Comment: @JDBeckton: I think I can guess which one they'll choose. I know the feeling though, my last perm employer decided to use beta versions of VS so as to be able to delay buying the licenses, and the one before then didn't want to buy TextPad licenses (about £15 each I think).

Comment: Yeah, it's just insane. These companies depend on technology so much yet continually balk at the idea of spending a few bucks to keep it up to date and feature rich.